# Assign to variable with arrow function doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

I have problem with arrow functions in javascript. When I try

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <p>Click the button to get the sum of the numbers in the array.</p>
        <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
        <p>Sum of numbers in array: <span id="demo"></span></p>
        <script>
            var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4];

            function myFunction() {
                 const result =
                    numbers.reduce(
                        (total, sum) => total + sum
                    );
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

it works ok. But when I try

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <p>Click the button to get the sum of the numbers in the array.</p>
        <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
        <p>Sum of numbers in array: <span id="demo"></span></p>
        <script>
            var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4];

            function myFunction() {
                 const result = numbers =>
                    numbers.reduce(
                        (total, sum) => total + sum
                    );
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

the *result* value is a string rather than a number. I tried different insertion options for parentheses, but it does not work for me. Where I am doing mistake?

Comment: Why are you adding `numbers =>`?

Comment: Because I tried to adapt the "arrow function" to this problem. In this example, yes, I have access to the numbers variable directly in the block, but I tried to do an anonymous function.

Comment: The problem is that you've defined `result` as a function, but then you didn't call the function using `result(numbers)`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need this `const result = numbers => numbers.reduce...`, or more specifically you don't need `numbers =>`, you can just make it so `const result = numbers.reduce(...`.

similar to what you have without using the arrow function.

### EDIT

I've updated the snippet to include your function which can accept a parameter.

By using:

```
var myFunction = (numberArr) =>{//code here}
```

You can then pass `numbers` into `myFunction()` or another array of you're choosing. Thus the html has been updated to reflect this:

```
<button onclick="myFunction(numbers)">Try it</button>
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <p>Click the button to get the sum of the numbers in the array.</p>
        <button onclick="myFunction(numbers)">Try it</button>
        <p>Sum of numbers in array: <span id="demo"></span></p>
        <script>
            var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4];

            var myFunction = (numberArr) => {
                 const result = numberArr.reduce(
                        (total, sum) => total + sum
                    );
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
                console.log(typeof result)
            }
            
           
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, I know, but I wanted to do it specifically using ES6 syntax.

Comment: Then for the anonymous function you would make it `var myFunction = () => { //code here//}` and that will work. I updated the script in my snippet.

Comment: I also updated it so it could accept numbers as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

This uses a self-executing anonymous arrow function to achieve what you want:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <p>Click the button to get the sum of the numbers in the array.</p>
        <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
        <p>Sum of numbers in array: <span id="demo"></span></p>
        <script>
            var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4];

            function myFunction() {
              const result = (numbers => numbers.reduce(
                (total, sum) => total + sum
              ))(numbers);
              document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

As other people have pointed out the extra function is not necessary in this specific case. However it shows how you could approach a similar problem where you need nested functions, e.g. if you are defining functions in loops.